# Does this R-Shiny with a csv upload function has security vulnerabilities?

Tags: r, security, shiny, xss, shiny-reactivity

I have a simple Shiny app that allows uploading of a simple csv file.

It expects that the csv file has 5 comma separated numbers in each row.

It then displays this file back to the user.

Here's the code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(
      2, wellPanel(
        fileInput("file1", "Choose csv file:",
                  multiple = FALSE,
                  accept = c("text/csv",
                             "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                             ".csv")
        )
      )
    )
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(
      2, tableOutput(outputId = "contents")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  uploaded <- reactive({

    req(input$file1)

    df <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath,
                   header = FALSE,
                   col.names = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"),
                   colClasses = rep("numeric", 5))
    return(df)
  })

  output$contents <- renderTable({
    uploaded()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

As you can see, there is no error handling. If the user uploads a file that differs from what the app expects, this can lead to unexpected results. I am ok with that - I expected that the users will be well behaved when using this app.

**Does this lead to some kind of security vulnerability?** My thinking is that because `read.csv()` expects 5 numeric columns, anything that is not 5 numeric columns will just be a useless bunch of `NA`. But, I have little experience with security so I could be very well wrong about this.